# How can i use multiple namespaces file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am having a Multiple namespace XML file as a source. i have to store all namespaces attributes values in a single table of DW,

Can any one suggest how can i use that type of file as a source?

Comment: lookie here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2fde216c-01ab-42a5-8b43-52f5f42d35bc/multiple-namespaces-in-an-xml-document

Comment: actually, i have read this article. But when i removed the namespaces then its display me a multiple output and remove the attribute linking there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently encountered this issue, so thought I would post a few notes of how this was resolved. Before attempting to load the multi-namespaced XML document it first needs to be converted using an XSLT transformation. SSIS can do this via the XML Task.

Pull an XML task from the tool bar and place it your Control Flow

[image]

Create a new XSLT file in the file system and use the following code as the content:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/2013/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" /> 
  <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="*"> 
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> 
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="@*"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Open the XML Task and set the following properties.

- Operation Type = XSLT
- SourceType = FileConnection
- Source = The File Connection that was set up for the Source that you set up
  for the Import file.
- SaveOperationResults =True
- DestinationType = File
- Destination = The File Connection that was set up for the destination file
- OverwriteDestination= Set as preferred
- SecondOperandType=File Connection
- SecondOperand= File that was set up to hold the above XSLT code

[image]

Once these items are added to your package, you should be able to run it and it will generate a second file with namespaces removed.