# How to load XML file using SSIS when my XML source is on the web

Tags: sql, xml, web, ssis

I have a XML source which is located on the web `(www.exampleXMLfile.com/XML)`

How will I load it to SSIS when the only option is from the file location or variable?

Answer (score 1):

you can download the xml file local to your pc using

"HTTP Connection Manager"     then read the xml file

Comment: please refer to this link, it may be usefull to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999695/how-can-i-use-multiple-namespaces-file-in-ssis

Comment: i tried the approach using the link you shared but they require it to be a file, not in web. i cannot also manually save the xml file through web since it is being updated everyday.

Comment: if there is a schedule for updating it every day, then you can make a simple package just for downloading it every day, and fire it using `Sql Agent` after that refer to the same link.

Comment: please mention the url having you xml file